# Use separate authentication model with Devise on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I have a simple solution I've made myself with the following objects:

- **Account** (has token field, that is returned when authenticating and used in API calls)
- **Authentication** (has auth_type/auth_id and reference to Account)

I have a separate **Authentication** model to be able to connect several ways of login (device UUID, email/password, twitter, facebook etc). But it seems that in all examples of Devise you use it on the **User** (**Account**) model.

Isn't that less flexible? For example OmniAuth module stores provider and id on the **User** model, what happens if you want to be able to login from both Twitter and Facebook, there is only room for one provider?

Should I use Devise on my **Account** model or the **Authentication** model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have been recently working on a project where I was using Devise to keep user's tokens for different services. A bit different case, but still your question got me thinking for a while.

I'd bind Devise to **Account** model anyway. Why? Let's see.

Since my email is the only thing that can identify me as a user (and you refer to **Account** as the User) I would place it in `accounts` table in pair with the password, so that I'm initially able do use basic email/password authentication. Also I'd keep API tokens in `authentications`.

As you've mentioned, OmniAuth module needs to store provider and id. If you want your user to be able to be connected with different services at the same time *(and for some reason you do)* then obviously you need to keep both provider-id pairs somewhere, otherwise one will simply be overwritten each time a single user authenticates. That leads us to the **Authentication** model which is already suitable for that and has a reference to **Account**.

So when looking for a provider-id pair you want to check `authentications` table and not `accounts`. If one is found, you simply return an `account` associated with it. If not then you check if account containing such email exists. Create new `authentication` if the answer is yes, otherwise create one and then create `authentication` for it.

To be more specific:

```
#callbacks_controller.rb
controller Callbacks < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksContoller
  def omniauth_callback
    auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    authentication =  Authentication.where(provider: auth.prodiver, uid: auth.uid).first
    if authentication
      @account = authentication.account
    else
      @account = Account.where(email: auth.info.email).first
      if @account
        @account.authentication.create(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid,
         token: auth.credentials[:token], secret: auth.credentials[:secret])
      else
        @account = Account.create(email: auth.info.email, password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
        @account.authentication.create(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid,
         token: auth.credentials[:token], secret: auth.credentials[:secret])
      end
    end
    sign_in_and_redirect @account, :event => :authentication
  end
end

#authentication.rb
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :provider, :uid, :token, :secret, :account_id
  belongs_to :account
end

#account.rb
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password
  has_many :authentications
end

#routes.rb
devise_for :accounts, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'callbacks' }
devise_scope :accounts do
  get 'auth/:provider/callback' => 'callbacks#omniauth_callback'
end
```

That should give you what you need while keeping the flexibility you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm just wondering about the token; shouldn't the token be on the Account as well? I'm probably gonna use TokenAuthenticatable strategy with devise, and it is usually used on the actual User/Account model? Is it possible to use the default strategies on the User/Account model but the TokenAuthenticatable on a separate model like Authentication?

Comment: Not sure if that is possible out of the box, but you can always override methods from DeviseSessionsController. I'd just personally use `omniauthable` though.

Answer (score 1):

You may separate all common logic to module and use only same table.

```
module UserMethods
  #...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UserMethods
  devise ...

end  

class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UserMethods
  self.table_name = "users"
  devise ...
end
```

And configure all devise model separately in routes, views(if necessary, see Configuring Views). In this case, you may easily process all different logic.

Also note that if you are in a belief that devise is for user model only, then you are wrong.

For ex. - `rails g devise Admin`

This will create devise for admin model.

More information [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-an-Admin-role).

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer the question, I don't want to add another role. The question is about whether to configure devise on the actual user model (or whatever, I'm using account) or on a separate authentication object to make it more flexible.