# Why provider and uid is mandatory with devise token auth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Can we move provider and uid field to separate table and maintain multiple account of same user.
I am using devise token auth. It is not allowing me to override the user model. which has uid and provider as an mandatory field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use separate authentication model with Devise on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647681/use-separate-authentication-model-with-devise-on-rails)

Comment: This has already been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14789700/1185180

Comment: Here,I am implementing with devise_token_auth . Can it be feasible with using that